# Using curl to login and post in rails with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, curl, devise

I am trying to create a bash script using curl to login to a rails app that uses devise and post on a form.

So far, I can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

curl \
  --verbose \
  --request GET \
  -c cookie \
  http://localhost:3000/login > tmpsession

# the ff is a hack to get the authenticity_token from the form
# and join it with the file 'data' for posting with curl
csrf_token=`cat tmpsession|grep 'authenticity_token'|grep -o 'authenticity_token.*' |grep -o 'value=.*' |cut -d ' ' -f1|cut -d \" -f2`
echo "authenticity_token=" > data ; echo $csrf_token >> data; echo "&" >> data; cat samplepost >> data 

curl \
  --verbose \
  -b cookie \
  --request POST \
  --data "user[username=admin&user[password]=xxpasswordxx&authenticity_token=$csrf_token" \
  http://localhost:3000/login
```

At this point, I am redirected to the admin/index page where it passes the `redirect_if_not_admin` before_filter

However, when I try to do this:

```
curl \
  --verbose \
  -b cookie \
  --request POST \
  --data @data
  http://localhost:3000/admin/posts
```

I get a `Filter chain halted as :redirect_if_not_admin rendered or redirected` in the logs which tells me that no user is currently logged in.

I was thinking that curl stores the session in the cookie and that this is being passed to the server. Is there a way to persist such a session with curl?

Comment: any luck on figuring this out?

Comment: @DannyClay: Did you find the answer for it.If yes, Please let us know